# How to write hex bytes to text file in Go?

Tags: file, go

I want to log port I/O operations to text file with Go language.
I wrote such a function:

```
func trace (buffer []byte){

    f, err := os.OpenFile("trace.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    for _, val := range buffer{         
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte{val});err!=nil{return}    
    }
}
```

But f.Write method writes to file ASCII string equivalent, but not []byte values. I need hexadecimal values, not strings in my log. I can not understand, why code `f.Write([]byte{"string"})` is valid, but something like `f.Write([]byte{fmt.Spirintf("%x", val)})` does not compile...

Comment: `fmt.Spirintf`does not compile because it is spelled `Sprintf`. Just do `fmt.Fprintf(f, "%02x", val)`

Comment: `[]byte{"string"}` is not valid Go code. Write does nothing special to its argument. It simply writes the bytes to its destination (in this case a file). If you want to write some representation of the bytes, you have to encode them appropriately before calling Write. Also, don't write bytes one at a time; that's horribly inefficient. Just call f.Write(buffer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you are looking for a solution to write to log the hexadecimal value of an ASCII string? ex. "41" == { 0x3**4**, 0x3**1** }?
If so, the code you are looking for is:

```
f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%x", buffer )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fnally, my working code is:

```
func trace (buffer []byte){

    if !Debug{return}

    f, err := os.OpenFile("trace.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    date:=fmt.Sprintf("%v", time.Now().Format("2018-01-02 15:01:02 PM Jan Mon"))

    if _, err := f.Write([]byte(date+"\r\n"));err!=nil{return}

    var counter int = 0

    for _, val := range buffer{
        if counter == 16{
            if _, err := f.Write([]byte("\r\n"));err!=nil{return}
            counter=0
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(f, "%02x ", val)
        counter++
    }

    if _, err := f.Write([]byte("\r\n\r\n"));err!=nil{return}

}
```